# It is possible to create a clone of a stack region?

Tags: c, memory, stack, buffer, clone

There is a way in C to create a clone of a stack region?

This is the idea:

1 - I allocate the first buffer of 20 characters (buff1)
2 - I allocate the second buffer "buff2" (somewhere) that is the shadow of buff1
3 - When I write something in buff1, buff2 will contain the same content of buff1

I don't know if it can be implemented through shadow memory.
I read something about shadow memory but I couldn't figure out how it worked.
I know I'm confused about this topic. If someone can clarify it for me, I'd be grateful.

This is the link on the shadow memory:  [Shadow memory](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/atc12/atc12-final39.pdf)

Comment: Is this different from aliasing pointers?

Comment: Well, I don't know which context you are working in, but one can map the same physical address to two different virtual ones. It will have it's pitfalls though..OTOH it is probably a XY-problem.

Comment: Why two buffers? If they were *always* the same you would only need one.

Comment: And: To "*clone*" I'd take as copying, which is a one-time action. What you are describing sounds more like "keeping in sync", which is a continuous action.